# change image features programmatically

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, image, image-processing

This is for a hobby project of mine.

It's a real world like political game. In it there is a lot of characters like politicians, military officers, religious figures etc. All these characters features are to be generated dynamically and stored in  as game progresses.    This includes, characters name, age, clan,race, political party, affiliations, character along with a ton of other features.

I'm using python flask as my server, and angularJS as front end.  I use SQLAlchemy-postgresql as database.

I would like to have a unique image (anime style or better),for each character that i have in Person able.Each person can be different according to their race, age etc. Like,have different skin tone, hair styles, eye color, face proportions, body size, Also uniforms, according to their current designations in the game. **How can i dynamically achieve this, using python or java-script.**

Also, i would like to have the image progresses e\with time. Example, add more wrinkles,saggy eyes, white hairs as the character ages.

Comment: What kind of graphics do you use, vector or raster?

Comment: i don't really need vector. simple png, or JPEG would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder what your expectations are.

```py
from dynamicPeopleVectorCreater.magic import *
```

if you are talking about a character creator, then you have to do it on your own. And i am absolutely sure it is hard work, even business company may spent a lot of time on this and the most implementations are not that amazing as it might was expected (fallout, saints row). Maybe you should concentrate on other features or create something like 20 static characters which will be randomly used.

If i had to do something like this i would start with creating base fragments like Head, Hair, Eyes, Beard, Mouth. And then mix them together with an image manipulation library of your choice.

E.g. user choosen head type 3 and hair type 10 and hair colortype 15:

Load Head (head_base_3.png)

Load Hair (hair_10.png)

- set color with image lib
- position the hair object to the right place with positioning data (x,y) which should be bound to the head because it might change onto head

and so on.

How to manipulate:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter17/

Good luck / Have Phun